# In mailchimp API v3 whats the alternative for user invite api from v2?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Heres the corresponding API spec in v2 :  https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/users/invite.php

Does v3 not support this?
I was not able to find it in documentation at : https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference